# Terraform force replaces AKS cluster during "terraform plan"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I have created a cluster, I am trying to test few use cases. Whenever I try to update the existing terraform and give **terraform apply** It force replaces my AKS cluster.

Is there anything related to **kube_admin_config**?

My terraform plan(second plan) returns something like below

```
module.aks.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
      - api_server_authorized_ip_ranges = [] -> null
      - enable_pod_security_policy      = false -> null
      + fqdn                            = (known after apply)
      ~ id                              = "/subscriptions/*****/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/aks-cluster-destroy" -> (known after apply)
      ~ kube_admin_config               = [
          - {
              - client_certificate     = "----*************************************************----"
              - client_key             = "----*************************************************----"
              - cluster_ca_certificate = "----*************************************************----"
              - host                   = "----*************************************************----"
              - password               = "----*************************************************----"
              - username               = "clusterAdmin_rg-aks-cluster-destroy_ask-cluster-destroy"
            },
        ] -> (known after apply)
      ~ kube_admin_config_raw           = (sensitive value)
      ~ kube_config                     = [
          - {
              - client_certificate     = ""
              - client_key             = ""
              - cluster_ca_certificate = ""
              - host                   = ""
              - password               = "----*************************************************----"
              - username               = "clusterUser_rg-aks-cluster-destroy_ask-cluster-destroy"
            },
        ] -> (known after apply)
```

Comment: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5460

Comment: I have gone through this GitHub issue and also similar issues, but didn't get proper solution. If you see in the same issue you mentioned here, at the end the user gave all the terraform plan logs. But no response after that, issue was closed automatically without response.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that this Is because of the certificate. Every time you apply this creates another certificate and that Is what trigger the recreation if the cluster with a newly issued certificate. If you comment the certificate blocks, you can see that is not going to recreate the cluster.

Comment: I do not have any certificate block in my terraform code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, subnet was the issue which force replaces the network and its dependencies.

Adding below line in "azurerm_subnet" resource fixed my issue.

`enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true`

My subnet block looks something like below after update.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                  = "${var.subnetname}"
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes      = var.akssubnet_address
  depends_on            = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet] 
  enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = true
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore the `kube_admin_config` and `kube_config` sections during the terraform plan using the appropriate lifecycle configuration in Terraform.

Just add this piece of code to the resource "k8s" declaration inside the module code:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "kube_admin_config",
      "kube_config"
    ]
  }
```

In general, this is a safe practice as those values are no updatable no matter what (in fact you would need to regenerate the master node to change them, aka rebuild the cluster).

You can also eliminate false "changes" by setting the other changing values to a value instead of leaving them out:

```
api_server_authorized_ip_ranges = []
enable_pod_security_policy = false
```

Comment: I tried to add ignore section in my k8s module but still i am facing same issue (replaces cluster)

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing and would like terraform to ignore the manual changes done to your resource you can choose to ignore changes to all attributes of a resource by adding the following code to the resource block

```
lifecycle {
   ignore_changes = all
 }
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes